# Exception Handling in C# Without Throwing It

Tags: c#, exception

Hey everybody I am just getting into C# and was going over exception handling. I am trying to find a way to trigger my custom exception without actually throwing it. It seems clunky to write throw new "custom exception" every time I want to error handle. With the throw line commented out my exception never gets triggered and I know that is because I am originally setting the object to null but can't find a way around this.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(String name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonException : Exception
{
    public PersonException() : base() {}

}


public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Person p = null;
        try
        {
           p = new Person("kim");
           //throw new PersonException();
        }
        catch (PersonException z) when(p.Name == "kim")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(z.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: _"trigger my custom exception without actually throwing it"_ There's no way to trigger an exception without throwing it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Expection is _meant_ to be thrown when something doesn't work as expected. You `throw` exception when something goes wrong, such as the `string` parameter is null or whatnot.

Comment: Don't use exception handling for normal control flow, use `if...else`. Exceptions are meant to be used for (rare) exceptional cases which often indicate bugs

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you fully understand the concept of exceptions (or your description does not make sense).
Your code will only ever enter the later part of the code below once an exception has occurred.  You are not throwing an exception and likewise your code will not result in an exception.  Seeing as no exception is occurring and you aren't manually throwing an exception I see no reason why it should ever enter the catch statement.  The whole idea is to catch the error, which occasionally you might have to throw.

```
try {
  // your code here
}
catch (Exception ex) {
 // here we catch a generic exception
}
```

...even this wouldn't activate your catch clause because attempting to cast an invalid string to an int would throw an error different to your custom PersonException.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(String name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}


try
{
  p = new Person("kim");
  p.Age = Convert.ToInt32("NOT AN INT");
}
catch (PersonException z) when(p.Name == "kim")
{
  Console.WriteLine(z.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances. You just need an `if` or `switch` block to check if the person's name is `"kim"`.

Answer (score 0):

All of the things already said by others apply and are good advice and I won't repeat them, but I think that what you're trying to do is better expressed as:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Person p = null;
        try
        {
           p = new Person("kim");

           if(p.Name == "kim")
           {
               throw new PersonException();
           }
        }
        catch (PersonException z)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(z.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

...So you only *throw* the exception when you have the error situation, rather than only *catch* it in certain situations.